# I can't see the russian alphabet in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, unicode, visual-studio-2008, console

I'm trying to output Russian words in Visual Studio 2008. I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");
    cout << "Я хочу видеть это по-русски!";
}
```

When I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the file in Visual Studio, I received the following prompt:

> Some Unicode characters in this file could not be saved in the current codepage. Would you like to save it in unicode?

I chose the option "Save with other Encoding" and selected "Cyrillic (Windows) - Codepage 1251." However, when I run my program, the console output appears as follows:

```
???????? ??? ????
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's the actual output when you run the program that is the problem?

Comment: Yes:) I need to see Я хочу видеть это по-русски!

Comment: Try to replace setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");
 with setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ".1251");

Comment: I have tried it already, it did not helped.

Comment: Are you out put to console window? If you want play with unicode character then you could use wcout, wstring, ..

Comment: No, I do not want. I can use ASCI I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't using Unicode characters set (wstring, wcout as @
Bình Nguyên have already mentioned). There are two ways to solve this problem: 
1. Use unicode characters set.
2. Go to Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Administrative Tab -> Language for non-Unicode programs -> Change system locale... -> choose Russia.

Comment: Thank You:) It works. But now I input 'ф' and it see it as 'д'(-28)

Comment: Let's clarify something: First, what solution you've used(1 or 2)? Second, you are typing into VS 2008 code editor's window ?

Comment: I used second solution and I'm typing into VS 2008 under Windows 7.

Comment: Check please your keyboards settings in Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Keyboards and languages-> Change keyboards.... There should be a russian keyborad shown as Russian(Russia). Some times people set wrong keyboard layout.

Comment: No, it is ok. I checked it. But it still messes Russian letters.

Comment: Hm.. it's strange, the last that I can think is to try to change your keyboard (physically ;) and check for software on your Windows, maybe there are some antiviruses that include something like antikeylogger program that block or changes keyboard input.

Comment: No, there is not, I tried to use OemToANSI but it is not help:( When I try it I have fail Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'str' was corrupted.