# Mistake in input Russian letter in Visual Studio 2008 throw console

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't see the russian alpabet in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790695/i-cant-see-the-russian-alpabet-in-visual-studio-2008)

I'm trying input symbol from console in Russian alphabet. This is code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

void main(){
    char c;
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");
    cout << "Я хочу видеть это по-русски!" << endl;
    cin >> c;
    cout << c;
}
```

I entered 'ф', but it prints 'д'. I tried to use

```
char buf[2];
char str[2];
str[0] = c;
str[1] = '\0';
OemToAnsi(buf, str);
```

But I have

```
+       str 0x0015fef4 "¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦ф¦¦¦¦d §"    char [2]
+       buf 0x0015ff00 "¦¦¦ф¦¦¦¦d §"    char [2]
```

And then I have an error Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'str' was corrupted.

Comment: What is the encoding of the .cpp file? It's visible in the "advanced save options" under "save as" dialog.

Comment: Maybe you need to use wide characters and strings, together with the wide character versions of the stream object (e.g. `std::wcout` and `std::wcin`)?

Comment: @Ilmo Euro encoding Cyrillic (Windows) - Codepage 1251

Comment: @Johan Lundberg no it was output, now it is input

Comment: Perhaps change the title of the question

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I tried wcin it did not helped. It sees 'ф' as L'д' now.

Comment: It is definitely not a duplicate of a mentioned question, as the first answer explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the set-up you're using is to have the source saved using cp1251 (Cyrillic Windows) and to have the console using cp866 (Cyrillic DOS). (This will be the default set up on Russian versions of Windows.) The problem you're running into seems to be that setting the locale as you do causes output to be converted from cp1251 to cp866, but does not cause the inverse conversion for input. So when you read a character in, the program gets the cp866 representation. This cp866 representation, when output, is incorrectly treated as a cp1251 representation and converted to cp866, resulting in the ф to д transformation.

I think the conversions is just done by the CRT based on the C locale, but I don't know how to enable a similar conversion for input. There are different options for getting your program to work.

- Manually convert input data from cp866 to cp1251 before echoing it.
- Replace `setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus")` which changes how the CRT deals with output with calls to `SetConsoleCP(1251); SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);` which will instead changes the console's behavior (and the changes will persist for the lifetime of the console rather than the lifetime of your program).
- Replace uses of cin and cout with Windows APIs using UTF-16. Microsoft's implementation of the standard library forces the use of legacy encodings and causes all sorts of similar problems on Windows. So just avoid it altogether.

Here's an example of the second option:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

#include <Windows.h>

void main(){
    char c;
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    std::cout << "Я хочу видеть это по-русски!\n";
    std::cin >> c;
    std::cout << c;
}
```

Assuming the source is cp1251 encoded then the output will appear correctly and an input ф will not be transformed into a д.

Comment: I did SetConsoleCP(866);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(866); and it worked. But now when I do not use 
setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus") it is not output correctly.

Comment: I believe the problem there is that the source is cp1251 and `setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus")` is required for strings to be converted from cp1251 to cp866 to match your call to SetConsoleOutputCP(866).

Answer (score 0):

The locale might be wrong. Try

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

This sets the locale to "the default, which is the user-default ANSI code page obtained from the operating system".

Comment: No, it did not help. When I tried it It does not show first cout correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int N = 34;
const char DosABC[N] = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
const char WinABC[N] = " ЎўЈ¤Ґс¦§Ё©Є«¬­®Їабвгдежзийклмноп";

std::string ToDosStr(std::string input)
{
    std::string output = "";
    bool Ok;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        Ok = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            if (input[i] == WinABC[j])
            {
                output += DosABC[j];
                Ok = true;
            }
            if (!Ok)
                output += input[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

I did it, and it works, but everybody welcome to find easier answer

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strxfrm/ *could* work, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Ilmo Euro I tested i, but it is not works :(